# Number of records Json Data has?

Tags: php, json

Is there a function  to find out the number of recodes that is being decoded

```
 $doctors=  json_decode(file_get_contents($url_containing_doctors_list),true);
```

So i would have to write a forloop and then increase the counter for Count variable ?

Comment: Come on. What does `json_decode()` return when the second parameter is `true`? And how do you get the number of the items in an array?

Comment: @bažmegakapa - So i would have to write a forloop and then increase the counter for Count variable ?

Comment: That's one way. The other is reading the manual ([Array Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)) and finding [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

Answer (score 2):

You can determine the length of the $doctors array using `count($docters)`. The json function does not return how many records it has unserialized.